# NGX Bootstrap Typeahead, with multiple template at once

Tags: angular, typeahead, ngx-bootstrap

I am using [ngx-bootstrap typeahead](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/typeahead) for auto-complete. Templates are populating if the response is an array. But I have a response as an object. My response is something like

```
{
  "set1": [],
  "set2": [],
  "set3": [],
}
```

Now I'm expecting to render different templates for each set of array.

```html
    <input (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoadingAlbum($event)"
                        (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelectAlbum($event)" [class.is-invalid]="searchFailed"
                        [isAnimated]="true" [typeaheadAsync]="true" [typeaheadScrollable]="true"
                        [typeaheadMinLength]="2" [typeahead]="rsAlbum$ "
                        [typeaheadItemTemplate]="albumItemCustomTemplate" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                        formControlName="albumItem" id="typeahead-http" placeholder="Enter name of album to search..."
                        type="text" />
```

```html
<ng-template #albumItemCustomTemplate class="suggestions">

    <!-- for set1 -->
    <ng-template let-index="index" let-model="item">
        <div class="_dropdown-item"> {{r}} {{ model.name }} </div>
    </ng-template>

    <!-- for set2 -->
    <ng-template let-index="index" let-model="item">
        <h5>This is: {{model | json}} Index: {{ index }}</h5>
          <div class="_dropdown-item">
            {{ model.name }}
            <span *ngIf="model.year != 0" class="year">- ({{ model.year }})</span>
        </div>  
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

Any enhacement that needs to be done in case to populate both the templates style in single call. I am getting error `Typeahead options.slice is not a function`. It works if response is simple array.

Comment: If you have control over the return object, I'd change the return type. Return an array of objects that have a type field for you to separate them on the front end. That way, you can easily change how you show them on client by using `ngIf`.

Comment: You didn't get the question. I need to separate and populate both `set1` and `set2` at the same time. So there is no question of `ngIf` since both needs to populating at the same time.

Comment: If I'm getting this right, I had to do something very similar recently. I was implementing a global search for different types of objects. What I did was I combined all the results on back-end into one single array. So when I get the results on the client side there is only one array, but all the objects has a type field. So it's easier to separate objects that way. But of course this is only possible if you have control over the back-end too. Just an idea.

Comment: @arunes Of course Yes, that's the first thought I had. I am writing backend APIs as well. If I change the response it would also reflect mobile exposed APIs(so I ignored). I was expecting to segregate at the UI end if they have a flexible component to this use case.

Comment: I see, I don't think they support this type of scenario. Maybe you can modify the result with rxjs pipes after you received in angular before passing it to ngx-typehead.